# Leaflet WFST style the markers

Tags: leaflet, wfs-t

I am working on the point data. I have managed to display the data using the WFST leaflet plugin.

```
var univ = new L.WFS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs',
        typeNS: 'HEC',
        typeName: 'Unis',
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        geometryField: 'the_geom',
        showExisting: true,
        maxFeatures: 500,
}).addTo(map);
```

Now my question is: how do I style my simple markers? I have tried following [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285311/leaflet-wfst-and-custom-markers-and-markercluster) link but it's not working for me.

Also maybe because I want to use L.ExtraMarkers.icon for markers.

Even if I alter my code markers do not style as I want them to.:

```
var univ = new L.WFS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs',
        typeNS: 'HEC',
        typeName: 'Unis',
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
        geometryField: 'the_geom',
        showExisting: true,
        maxFeatures: 500,
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
                           switch (feature.properties.Sector){
                                   case 'Public' : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({icon: 'fa-graduation-cap', markerColor: 'orange', shape: 'circle', prefix: 'fa'})});
                                   case 'Private' : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({icon: 'fa-graduation-cap', markerColor: 'cyan', shape: 'circle', prefix: 'fa'})});
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, in case this helps someone else too, you can add this line right after the "case Public" and "case Private" lines:

```
       default: return L.marker(latlng,{icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({icon: 'fa-graduation-cap', markerColor: 'green', shape: 'circle', prefix: 'fa'})});
```

to give a color to the remaining "other values" than Public and Private

Answer (score 3):

So I solved it. For the L.WFST point feature, you need to pass two arguments: the options and a GeoJSON which you can use to style the marker. So the code now looks like this:

```
var univ = new L.WFST(
        {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/HEC/wfs',
            typeNS: 'HEC',
            typeName: 'Unis',
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG4326,
            geometryField: 'the_geom',
            showExisting: true,
            maxFeatures: 500,
        },
    new L.Format.GeoJSON({
        pointToLayer(feature, latlng) { 
            switch (feature.properties.Sector){
                case 'Public' : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({icon: 'fa-graduation-cap', markerColor: 'orange', shape: 'circle', prefix: 'fa'})});
                case 'Private' : return L.marker(latlng,{icon: L.ExtraMarkers.icon({icon: 'fa-graduation-cap', markerColor: 'cyan', shape: 'circle', prefix: 'fa'})});
            }
        },
    })
).addTo(map);
```

Posting the answer in case it helps someone else.

Comment: I'm interested but I have so much difficulties to implement it. What is the L.extramarkers version your're using?

Comment: I'm using this: https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers

What difficulties are you having? Since I just implemented it I might be able to help.

Comment: I just corrected my WFS layer in Qgis/Postgis. Maybe because the column wasn't in 'varchar', it was unreadable. Now it works

Comment: Now I'm using the last version like you do, copying everything on my server , with fontawesome  5. An older version made the icon to show not aligned